# remove the element that's leaved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I have mouseleave event. When I leave the element, I wan't to remove that element that I mouseleaved from (if this give sense). Example below, and what I tried. I supposed that I can't do it that way because that's not how it works (I guess), but what is the propper way to do it? Atm. I can't use a selector like:

```
$('#wrapper').remove()
```

rather than

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#wrapper', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).remove());
  alert('Mouse leaved and wrapper should be removed');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#wrapper', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).remove);
  alert('Mouse leaved and wrapper should be removed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">asdcasdcasd</div>
```

Comment: Your code works when you are using `.remove()`, which you have listed in your first two sections, but not in the snippet, which just has `.remove`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remove()` is a method not property. Use `remove()` not `remove`

```js
$(document).on('mouseleave', '#wrapper', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).remove());
  alert('Mouse leaved and wrapper should be removed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">asdcasdcasd</div>
```

Comment: I can see that it must have been something to do with that the #wrapper is appended in my case. Anyway I will accept your answer, It was a typo reason without remove() :).

Comment: @simon, what do you want to achieve from your code. Your event is bound to `#wrapper` element causing `this` to be referenced to `#wrapper`.